# Jenkins python win32com error

Tags: python, jenkins, window

My python script can be passed running in window command line, but fails in Jenkins.
It seems related to win32com.client. Jenkins cannot recognize COM which use for the communication of Python with Microsoft.

Python script:

```
import win32com.client
import os
def current_path():
    addr = os.getcwd()
    addr = addr + "\\"  
    return addr

wordapp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application") 
wordapp.Visible = 0 
doc = wordapp.Documents.Add()
doc.SaveAs(current_path()+ r'TestReport.docx')
```

Error in Jenkins build:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson1805497081946812814.py", line 11, in <module>
    doc.SaveAs(current_path()+ r'TestReport.docx')
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 522, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: Add.SaveAs
```